# Copying files to USB

Tags: usb, files, usb-drive, copy

I used a USB to make Ubuntu 16.04 bootable on my desktop (which is Ubuntu 16.04) for installation on my laptop. Then I could not format the drive. I have done this now, but. I can not copy files to the USB on my desktop (where I used Gparted to fix the format issue) but I can on my laptop? 
I wish to make the USB drive good for both desktop and laptop.
Any ideas please.

Comment: Rewrite the partition table in Gparted, and then create a single FAT32 partition spanning the entire unallocated space.

Comment: I did that already to get it to work. It does work in my laptop but not on my desktop. Both have Ubuntu 16.04 installed.

Comment: When I try and paste a file into the USB stick there is not a paste option, its greyed out. I have tried again and the result is the same.

Comment: Try running Nautilus with root perms: `gksudo nautilus`

Comment: I did what you said but I still could not copy and paste (paste still greyed out) then I tried to format the USB stick, it formatted and now I can paste into the drive as I could before. Thank you. I wonder if it will still work on my laptop..... That is great it works. Thank you. Do you know how I can unlock a read only USB stick, I pulled it out of Ubuntu without ejecting it?